# Breakpoint on the .init Section of a Shared Library

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, elf, inkscape

I tried to run `inkscape-0.92.3` in `gdb`. Precisely, I tried to set a breakpoint on the first address of the `.init` section in its main shared library (i.e., `/usr/lib/inkscape/libinkscape_base.so`). The address is `0x7ffff6ebd9d0` based on the information returned by `info files`. But when I set the breakpoint on this address using `b *0x7ffff6ebd9d0`, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff6ebd9d0
```

This address is the address of the `_init` function of this library. The same symbol, also, exists in other shared libraries. So I can put a breakpoint on this symbol using `b _init`, which leads to a lot of sub-breakpoints. This time all breakpoints work fine and I can `c(ontinue)` until I reach the `_init` symbol for the `libinkscape` shared library. Does anybody know the reason for the error in the raw address case?

Comment: Did you rerun program after obtaining the address `0x7ffff6ebd9d0`?

Comment: Yes. But as Employed Russian says, the address should be mapped, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know the reason for the error in the raw address case?

The reason: this address isn't mapped yet (the library hasn't been loaded yet).

It works for `break _init` case because GDB can check whether any newly-loaded shared library defines that symbol. But it's not smart enough to check whether address `0x7ffff6ebd9d0` becomes breakpoint-able.

You can work around this by using `(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 1`. GDB will then stop every time new shared libraries are loaded, *before* running their initializers.

Once `libinkscape_base.so` shows up, you will be able to use the address breakpoint as desired.